# How is Scene.isLoaded determined?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cannot find anything in docs that breaks down the scene loading process and how the `Scene.isLoaded` property is determined.

I need to mock large scene loading and cannot find a way to delay a scene's loading. It would be useful to understand the flow especially when needing to load external assets in the scene and only mark the scene as loaded via code.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) and especially [`allowSceneActivation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html) which allows you to do exactly that: Delay a scenes loading and e.g. display a loading screen meanwhile.

Example from the docs:

```c#
// This script lets you load a Scene asynchronously. 
// It uses an asyncOperation to calculate the progress and outputs 
// the current progress to Text (could also be used to make progress bars).

// Attach this script to a GameObject
// Create a Button (Create>UI>Button) and a Text GameObject (Create>UI>Text) 
// and attach them both to the Inspector of your GameObject
//In Play Mode, press your Button to load the Scene, and the Text 
// changes depending on progress. Press the space key to activate the Scene.
//Note: The progress may look like it goes straight to 100% if your Scene doesn’t have a lot to load.

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AsyncOperationProgressExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text m_Text;
    public Button m_Button;

    void Start()
    {
        //Call the LoadButton() function when the user clicks this Button
        m_Button.onClick.AddListener(LoadButton);
    }

    void LoadButton()
    {
        //Start loading the Scene asynchronously and output the progress bar
        StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadScene()
    {
        yield return null;

        //Begin to load the Scene you specify
        AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene3");
        //Don't let the Scene activate until you allow it to
        asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;
        Debug.Log("Pro :" + asyncOperation.progress);
        //When the load is still in progress, output the Text and progress bar
        while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            //Output the current progress
            m_Text.text = "Loading progress: " + (asyncOperation.progress * 100) + "%";

            // Check if the load has finished
            if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9f)
            {
                //Change the Text to show the Scene is ready
                m_Text.text = "Press the space bar to continue";
                //Wait to you press the space key to activate the Scene
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //Activate the Scene
                    asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also checkout [`sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html): as stated in the docs

> Add a delegate to this to get notifications when a Scene has loaded.

This happens after the scene has been loaded and afaik **after** the `Awake` calls finished. You can easily test this by using a script like

```c#
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Awake");
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded");
    }
}
```

You will see both the

```c#
Awake
OnSceneLoaded
```

debugs in the console meaning that `Awake` was called before `OnSceneLoaded`.

**→ At this moment I would also expect the [`Scene.isLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-isLoaded.html) to be set to true.**

Comment: thanks for the reply, I do make use of the `SceneManager.LoadAsync` to track the scene loading progress. This will let you hook into the scene loading progress. What I am trying to find out, is ***how*** Unity determines when is scene is loaded i.e. what factors must be achieved in order for it to be "loaded". As an example in the above, how could you delay/control the loading time within `Scene3` to mock a large load time?

Comment: As said afaik when all `Awake` calls are done the scene is considered loaded. I'm not sure if you can mock a large loading time .. you can only delay it within the async load routine before doing `allowSceneActivation = true` e.g. `yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);` or something like that.

Comment: Delaying `Awake()` was the first thing I tried. But `Awake()` can not be a coroutine to return `IEnumerator` like most other Monobehavior methods. `Start` has no impact on loading it seems. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: making `Start` an `IEnumerator` doesn't really dealy it anyway ;) Every coroutine's `MoveNext` call is done right after the `Update` call. It is just a shorthand for starting a coroutine in `Start` .. the effect would be the same. They only option would be to create some heavy load like File IO .. but this would block the entire app of course ;)